# RoR API - when I switch db from sqlite to postgres, any updated objects in API array are moved to end of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

When I update an object in my sqlite API with ajax, it keeps the order of my object array - so the front end looks the same. When I update an object in the API after switching the db to postgres, it changes the order of the array - mostly placing the updated objects at the end of the array. Any ideas what's going on here?

I've tried deleting and remaking the database, no luck. I switched back to sqlite and is working normally again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL order is not guaranteed.  If you desire a particular order, the safest thing to do is to add a sort key to your records, and make sure you're doing an `ORDER BY` on your select statement.

The fact that SQLite is preserving your ordering is kind of a "mistake" of implementation.  You should not rely on the engine to do anything outside the specification.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it with with a '.order(:id)' method in the controller. Much appreciated.

Comment: @CaleSwitzer `order(:created_at)` might be a better choice as that seems to be your intent. You're better off not assuming anything about `id`s beyond uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html):

> After a query has produced an output table (after the select list has been processed) it can optionally be sorted. If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on. A particular output ordering can only be guaranteed if the sort step is explicitly chosen.

That said: without an explicit `ORDER` clause the order of the returned records is kind of random.

Comment: Thank you! See my reply to Paul.